# Add new cells to Sum formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a spreadsheet where I insert two columns prior to my total columns and populate with data.

Eg.

```
  A       B             C       D             E       F         G       H
  May-12                Jun-12                Jul-12            Total
  Spend   #Trans        Spend   #Trans        Spend   #Trans    Spend   #Trans 
3 $100    1             $200    3             $400    10        --->See formula Below
```

The sum formula for Total Spend up to Jun-12 is:

```
     =SUM(A3,C3)
```

Could I store the cell values into an array and then write the formula?

Now need to add Jul-12

```
     =SUM(A3,C3,E3)
```

My question is when I insert the columns for July data in between Jun-12 and Total, how can I write a macro to update the formula to add the new column for Spend and #Trans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=SUMIFS(3:3,2:2,"Spend")
```

or if you are using Excel 2003 or earlier

```
=SUMIF(2:2,"Spend",3:3)
```